# CocoaPods Swift and Objective-C Pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Can you have both Swift and Objective-C Pods? I currently only have Objective-C pod installed, and trying to add "SwiftyJSON" but it is a swift pod. It is telling me to add use_frameworks!. but that messes up my Objective-C pod.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to use `use_frameworks!` with both Objective-C and Swift. Keep in mind these are specific to iOS 8 and newer. Also in theory the Objective-C library you're using could have strange compatibility issues with frameworks.